# I would like to add 2 random numbers on the end of each username created from a file. How would I do this in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

```
!#/bin/bash
 echo "which list of names would you like to add?"
 read file
 USER_LIST="(cut -d " " -f 1,2,3 $file --output-delimeter='.') " 
 echo "$USER_LIST | while read user; do echo "useradd "$user"";
 done
```

using userlist.txt
james bond
ben afflack
john stewart
abdul rahim muhammad

CURRENT OUTPUT

```
james.bond
ben.afflack
john.stewart
abdul.rahim.muhammad
```

desired output

```
james.bond22
ben.afflack13
john.stewart11
abdul.rahim.muhammad83
```

What would be the easiest way to add the numbers to the end? I was looking at doing something along the lines of  .$((RANDOM%10)).$((RANDOM%10))

any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Bash allow to print formatted strings directly to a variable. So: `printf -v user '%s%02d' "$user" "$((RANDOM%100))"`

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track with using $RANDOM, however its easier than you think. I was able to do it with the following:

```sh
user=james.bond
rand=${RANDOM:0:2}
if [ ${#rand} -lt 2 ]
then 
  rand=0$rand
fi
user=$user$rand
```

This sets user to `james.bond23` (or some other 2 digit number). You just use parameter expansion to pick out the first two numbers generated by $RANDOM.

Comment: how would it look worked into my script though? james.bond wouldn't be in the script since im reading the file and its applying it to everyone in that textfile.

Comment: Yeah that was just a singular example, you can put everything except for the first line after the `while read user; do`. This will print out the “new” user when you call echo.

Answer (score 0):

Refering to your question on how to implement this in a loop I have added a small snippet without using `cut`.

---

Assuming you have the file `userlist.txt` with the following content

```
james bond 
ben afflack 
john stewart 
abdul rahim muhammad
```

In this file each name is seperated by a *new line* (`\n`).

The reading can be done with a single while loop. With the following quick approach you are able to print the desired the output:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "which list of names would you like to add?"
# Read your file
read file
echo "Reading $file."

# Iterating trough each line of your text file. 
while read p; do
  # Accessing each element with $p: e. g. echo $p

  # Apply a string manipulation on $p, add a 
  # random number at the end and print it out
  echo ${p// /.}.${RANDOM:0:2}

done < $file # Your filename of your text file
```

The part `${p// /.}` is called bash string manipulation. If you are interested in this, you can take a look at [Shell-Parameter-Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). But it's not specified by POSIX. Not all Unix shells implement it.